# Reading from socket stream

Tags: c, sockets

I want to create a simple request / response application in C using sockets. I have come up to the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>



int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    struct addrinfo hints;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    int currentChar = 0;

    struct addrinfo *addr;

    int conn_s = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    getaddrinfo( "google.com", "80", &hints, &addr );

    connect( conn_s, addr->ai_addr, sizeof( struct sockaddr_in ) );

    FILE* stream = fdopen( conn_s, "w+" );

    if ( stream != NULL ) {

        char *http_request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";

        fprintf( stream, "%s", http_request );

        do {

            currentChar = fgetc( stream );
            printf( "%c", currentChar );

        } while ( currentChar != EOF );

        fclose ( stream );
        freeaddrinfo( addr );

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Basically, the console displays the result of the stream (so the response of the HTTP request) but it seems like the process never terminates. The end of the program is never reached.

I guess **currentChar** never holds the value **EOF** but I don't know why.

Comment: You might want to read about [HTTP persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

Comment: If you're talking to an HTTP server, don't write it yourself: use libcurl.

Answer (score 0):

This is because HTTP/1.1 has persistent connections (aka keepalive), you can make the server disconnect after each request by using HTTP/1.0 and adding `Connection: close` header